# Mapbox access token restrict to URL does not work with github pages?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, deck.gl

I am publishing a web page in github, https://djouallah.github.io/keplergl/ , and I am restricting the access only to those URL,(I am trying different combination)

https://djouallah.github.io

https://djouallah.github.io/keplergl

https://djouallah.github.io/keplergl/

https://djouallah.github.io/keplergl/index.html

but mapbox does not render, it works with my public token, which i can't use as i want to keep it private. here is the code for the html page

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>deck.gl solar Farm  Example</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/deck.gl@^7.0.0/dist.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.53.1/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>      
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    const {DeckGL, ScatterplotLayer} = deck;  
    function get_colour( d ) {
        if( d === '1-pile' ) {
            return [0,128,255]
        } else if ( d === '2-Tracker') {
            return [255,100,128]
        } else if ( d === '3-module') {
            return [128, 128, 128]
        } else {
            return [255, 255, 255]
        }
    }
    new DeckGL({
      mapboxApiAccessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoibWltNzg3IiwiYSI6ImNrMDFwbnNxajJseG8zY21sY2l0Mmp3MnMifQ.LQMXWc8aDucjeSkqGvRNPw',
      mapStyle: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-streets-v9',
      longitude: 5.21,
      latitude:  35.504,
      zoom: 15,
      minZoom: 5,
      maxZoom: 20,
      pitch: 40.5,
      layers:[ 
        new ScatterplotLayer({
        id: 'scatter-plot',
        data: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/djouallah/interactivie_map/master/data.json',
        radiusScale: 3,
        radiusMinPixels: 0.25,
        getPosition: d => [d[0], d[1], 0],
        getFillColor: d => get_colour( d[3] )
      })
      ]
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Comment: no, I did not know what's wrong

Comment: I have solved this problem. Do you add accessible URLs for your public key?

Comment: you mean this Default public token !!!, no I added only URL for this specific token

Comment: I am facing the same problem, I want to restrict the access token only to the githubpages.. .and it does not work. Have you solved it?

Comment: Was this ever solved? My mapbox is completely blank when viewing on github page

Answer (score 0):

I read through [this documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/accounts/guides/tokens/#url-restrictions) and added my github page as https://my_username.github.io/ the API key functions as expected, only allowing requests to come from that origin. It did take a few minutes after I changed the token to be URL restricted before it actually took effect.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).